# wire is dark, not bright

Tags: wire, copper

If I strip an insulated wire, and the wire under the insulation is dark, not bright, and it's this way not just at the end but in the middle too, should I discard that wire for use? Has it been damaged from too high resistance?

Comment: Dark as in just dark, or dark as in corroded? Wires aren't damaged by resistance, but by heat melting the sheathing.  Got a picture?

Comment: What Machavity said plus copper oxidizes and turns dark. It could have oxidized during manufacture or later. Usually not a problem unless you are trying to solder it.

Comment: oxidation may indicate its been exposed to moisture. To a certain degree you can still use it if you take care to remove the oxidation at any connection. That said there are all kinds o fwire and applications, its hard to be generic.

Answer (score -1):

It can oxidize, but if you can test it for connectivity it should be fine.